# how to correctly use other composables like a pinia or vue router in composable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to use router or pinia store in composable
I know two ways:

1. Pass the router in composable arguments
2. use it directly in composable itself
   which one is correct?
   It's just that if we use it in composable, then we create additional instances of that router or pinia store

i searched, but nothing found

Comment: Can you clarify what's the problem? A composable is supposed to *compose* other composables. It's correct to use useRouter and useStore there.

Comment: @EstusFlask the problem is I can't figure out how to use them in composable or pass as arguments

Comment: Just call them as you'd do inside a component. With a composable, you extract the code from setup function to a separate function, so it could be reused, it's as simple as that. Please, explain your case further if there's something more specific that troubles you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.